# I am using Slick Slider in my asp.net project. Once i remove a slide via "slickRemove", sub slider first slide, content become empty

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am working on asp.net mvc project, that includes 10 slides(**main slider**). In 08th slide included another slider(**Slide inside slide - sub slider**). This sub slides are generate in dynamically according to the retrieve number of records in Database. To achieve this I used **Slick Slider** plugin.
   The problem is I removed a slide (07th slide -> 06th index) in Main Slider by using a slick slider feature which is called **"slickRemove"** The

**As a example :** $('#slick_MainSlider').slick('slickRemove', index);

Once I removed it, the index removed in successfully. But in 08th slide(In Main slider) which Included another Slider ("slick_SubSlider")  First Index content not showing But First slide exist (Only content not showing in first index in sub slickslider)

Following I have provided code sample what I have tried to do. ( run code snippet not working, please refer only the HTML and JS Section)

```js
if($(".slide_LineChart").parent().parent().hasClass("slick-slide")) 
{
               
var index = $('.slide_LineChart').parent().parent().index()-1;
    console.log(index);
    $('#slick_MainSlider').slick('slickRemove', index);
                
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Slick Slider -->
<div id="slick_MainSlider" class="slider">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_1"><canvas id="line_barchart"></canvas></div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_2"><canvas id="line_barchart"></canvas></div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_3"><canvas id="line_barchart"></canvas></div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_4"><canvas id="line_barchart"></canvas></div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_5"><canvas id="line_barchart"></canvas></div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_6"><canvas id="line_barchart"></canvas></div>
 
  <!-- This is the slide i am removing --> 
  <div class="col-md-12 slide_LineChart" id="slide_7">
      <canvas id="line_Chart"></canvas>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Inside this slide, include sub slider --> 
    <div class="col-md-12" id="slide_8">
    <!-- Sub slider - start -->
    <div id="slick_SubSlider" style="">
      <div id="sub_slide1">Content</div>
      <div id="sub_slide2">Content</div>
      <div id="sub_slide3">Content</div>
      <div id="sub_slide4">Content</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sub slider - end -->
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Finally i wanna say the main problem is **when i remove 07th slide**(In Main Slick Slider), The **First slide (01 the slide as given in code snippet) inside slick Sub Slider**(sub slider included in 08th slide in Main Slick slider), **not showing it content, but the sub slide is there with empty content,**

I am looking for a kind solution for this problem.
Thanks.